# Django webp converter tag static_webp not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, static, django-templates, webp

I installed the webp_converter package at documented [Here](https://django-webp-converter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

```
{% load webp_converter %}

This is not working which I want to add static_webp
<img src="{% static_webp 'modelImage.url' %}">

This is working fine
<img src="{{ modelImage.url }}">

From Official Doc says
<img src="{% static_webp 'img/hello.jpg' %}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not customize the output to the template using `{% static_webp 'modelImage.url' %}`. But I was able to convert the file when uploading and store the files immediately in the desired format (webp). My solution may be useful for those who are developing a new project because my method does not assume previously saved files in the model.
So let's start in order.

1. **models.py**
   In my model (Catalog) I have overridden the path to where the images are stored by calling the function (`rename_file`). The function (`rename_file`) renames the expansion of our file to .webp, creating the correct `obj.url` . This must be done immediately. Because the `obj.url` has the attribute read only.

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from datetime import date

   image_path = os.path.abspath(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/photos/asics/' + date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/'))

   def rename_file(instance, filename):
       if filename.find('.') >= 0:
           dot_index = (len(filename) - filename.rfind('.', 1)) * (-1)
           filename = filename[0:dot_index]
       filename = '{}.{}'.format(filename, 'webp')
       return os.path.join(image_path, filename)

   class Catalog(models.Model):
       photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_file, blank=True)
   ```
2. **admin.py**
   Images are added to my application through the admin panel. So I decided to convert the images in this file, but it doesn't matter. Here I use signals (post_save) to call the function (convert_image), which converts the image to the desired format (.webp) and replace the Origanal file with a new file.

   ```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Catalog
    from PIL import Image
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Catalog)
    def convert_image(instance, **kwargs):
        if image_name:
            im = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
            output_path = str(image_name)
            im.save(output_path, 'webp')

     class CatalogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
             global image_name
             image_name = obj.photo
             super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
   ```